# `sudo service postgresql status` shows postgresql is running, but there is no process for the given PID when running `ps aux`?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

It looks like it's running when I check the service status:

```
ubuntu@demos:/etc/postgresql/10/main$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-03-11 09:11:44 UTC; 3min 28s ago
  Process: 18643 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18643 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 11 09:11:44 demos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:11:44 demos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

But when I look at the list of processes...

```
ubuntu@demos:/etc/postgresql/10/main$ ps aux | grep 18643
ubuntu   18811  0.0  0.2  14856   996 pts/7    S+   09:16   0:00 grep --color=auto 18643
```

Nothin.

Trying to restart the postgresql service doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

Tried looking at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log` but this file seems to be empty.

I also ran `journalctl -u postgresql.service` and this is all I see:

```
Feb 08 15:38:30 demos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:06:24 demos systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:06:24 demos systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:06:24 demos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:06:24 demos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:11:36 demos systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:11:44 demos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:11:44 demos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:17:18 demos systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Mar 11 09:17:18 demos systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:17:18 demos systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 11 09:17:18 demos systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Comment: Note: the process was `/bin/true` and it exited (`code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS`).

Comment: So it looks like postgresql is not actually installed then? But for some reason the startup script is still present?

Comment: Found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/894560/postgresql-systemd-service-is-bin-true) - which seems to have fixed my issue

Comment: Good job. If you answer your own question and explain the issue then I will upvote the answer. Link-only answers are low quality so please make it standalone.